# Frequent Logout issue in drupal 7 hosted in azure cloud server

Tags: drupal

Frequent Logout issue in Drupal 7 hosted in azure cloud server.

We have deployed the Drupal site from development to staging. The site works fine but the problem is we are getting logout very frquently. we couldn't find out why this happening?.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal stores user information in PHP sessions. PHP sessions are stored usually in `/temp` dir. Exact information where sessions are stored can be seen in phpinfo() output, variable `session.save_path`. So to me it looks like that something is deleting files from that tmp dir. Some cron job?

Also, I don't know about azure cloud, but some cloud host solutions are being re-initialized on some specific time period, meaning all temp files are getting deleted.